# Subclipse 4.3.0, Eclipse Oxygen repository conflict solving

Tags: eclipse, svn, repository, subclipse, merge-conflict-resolution

as I said I'm using `Eclipse Oxygen` with `Subclipse 4.3.0` plugin and I fall in a little problem but, I prefer to ask rather than try casually. The situation is this:

- We are two persons developing and we both updated the project from repository
- We should work in different areas but, accidentally we create the SAME file (just 2 or 3 file were created by both us)
- My collegue commit first and put those file (which I also have locally) in the repository
- Now when I synchronize the project I see conflict on those file

I want to replace those files with mine (local version). How can I do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Right-click the file and choose _Mark as Merged_ and then commit it. By the way Eclipse Oxygen is pretty old, please upgrade.

Comment: Mark as Merged is not visible if I do right click on those file...

Comment: I have solved..

Comment: Sorry, I missed that _Mark as Merged_ is Subversive, not Subclipse. If you have a solution, add it as a self answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved by overwriting my file with the one in repository -> than I apply my changes again -> commit.

This is an overkill.. I haven't used svn for a long time (company switched to Git) I remember a wonderful way to solve conflict:

Opening conflicted file in a comparator view (doubled view, local and repository). From here I was able to bring code from repository-file to local and viceversa. When the square on the top of window became green -> mark as merged.

This is the plugin I want!! I can't believe subclipse doesn't do this!! they go back instead of forward??

Thanks